# How can i overlap graphs using Python?

Tags: python, graph, visualization

I am trying to do some graphs with Python. I used this data file: https://datahub.io/core/global-temp/r/annual.csv.

```
Annual = pd.read_csv("https://datahub.io/core/global-temp/r/annual.csv", sep=',', keep_default_na=False)
```

The Data Set includes 2 sources for the same timeline. I want to show the common graph and every one for their own. Also 3 Graphs.

```
alt.Chart(Annual, title= "Annual Temperature Change from 1880-2016").mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('Year:O'),
    alt.Y('Mean'),
)
```

I was able to filter sources from each other

```
gcag = Annual.loc[0::2]
gistemp = Annual.loc[1::2]
```

How can I bring "Annual"(which is already working) and "gcag", "gistemp" all together? Do you have any tips for an beginner? Maybe more than a line graph...

Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had any experience with the `alt` library yet, but based on what you described, here is what I did that might be helpful for you:

- the dataset has 2 different sources and you mentioned that you wanted a third layer that you named as "common". Based on that, I assumed you want an average value between GISTEMP and GCAG, for each year. Thus, here is the snippet you could try:

```
avg_temp_by_year = Annual.groupby('Year').agg({'Mean':'mean'}).reset_index()
avg_temp_by_year['Source'] = 'ANNUAL'
```

- next, append this new dataset to the pre-existing dataset, by doing:

```
new_df = pd.concat([Annual, avg_temp_by_year], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

- plot the three graphs. For this example, I used the `searbon` library, which is a great one for data visualizations:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=new_df, x='Year', y='Mean', hue='Source')
```

PS1: `hue` is a parameter that you can pass to create different layers on the same graph. In this example, it receives the `Source` column, since it is comprised of the 3 possible values now (ANNUAL, GISTEMP and GCAG)

PS2: I encourage you to read the docs (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and try to find a better way to display those lines.

I hope this answer helps you!
Good luck ;)

[image]